# How to pass an integer as a key in python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have written the following code, that works fine when I pass a character or a string as a key.

```
def myfunc(**num):
    for i in num:
        print(i, num[i])

myfunc(a="One", b="Two")
```

However, when I try to pass integers instead of a or b, for example:

```
myfunc(1="One", 2="Two")
```

I get the following message:

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Is there anything I could do about this?

Comment: Sorry, why would you want to pass integers as argument names? Do you really mean to do that or were you trying to call `myfunc(a=1, b=2)`

Comment: @GalodoLeste I would basically like to create a dict like this: {1:"One",  2:"Two"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, as all keyword arguments are [required to be strings](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/117441.html). More technically as [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11082165/brian) pointed out, [keyword arguments are syntactically required to be identifiers by definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls).

The error message your example gets is cryptic, but you can easily demonstrate this by passing a dictionary with integer keys as the keyword arguments:

```
def myfunc(**num):
    for i in num:
        print(i, num[i])


myfunc(**{1: 'one', 2: 'two'})
# TypeError: keywords must be strings
```

If you must use integer keys, just pass a dictionary as an argument instead and avoid all the problems:

```
def myfunc(num):
    for i in num:
        print(i, num[i])


myfunc({1: 'one', 2: 'two'})
```

Comment: @DanielHao I like to use [the python-dev mail archive](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/). This specific I had saved in my reading list from a while back though (I tend to do that when I come across something that could be useful later).

Comment: I think it be clearly / more correct to say that keyword arguments are syntactically required to be _identifiers_. That is, after all, [exactly how they're defined](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls).

Comment: @Brian Good call, I've edited my answer. Just for simplicity/beginner's sake, I've left in the original, but added your note right next to it.

Answer (score -1):

```
def print_value(my_dict, key):
    print(my_dict[key])

# Define a dictionary
my_dict = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}

# Pass an integer key to the function
print_value(my_dict, 2)  # Output: two
```

is this what you are after?

Comment: This is not remotely close to OP's code, nor does it answer the question.